# How to format data in a FormControl

Tags: angular, form-control, formgroups

I am using angular 14 with typed FormGroup.  I need to format the input textbox to be currency.   Can't figure out how to format the "paymentAmount" field as currency:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()" [formGroup]="paymentFormGroup">
  <div class="table-row">
    <div class="table-cell-label">
      <label for="paymentAmount">Payment Amt:</label
      ><label class="required">*</label>
    </div>
    <div class="table-cell-input">
      <input
        id="paymentAmount"
        type="text"
        formControlName="paymentAmount"
        class="input-text"
        [ngClass]="
          isSubmitted &&
          formControls['paymentAmount'].errors &&
          formControls['paymentAmount'].errors['required']
            ? 'input-required'
            : ''
        "
      />
    </div>
  </div>
```

And in the ts file:

```
export interface CustomerPaymentInfo {
  name: string | undefined;
  email?: string | null;
  accountNumber: number | undefined;
  paymentAmount: number | undefined;
  accountBalance: number | undefined;
  newAccountBalance: number | undefined;
}


const info: CustomerPaymentInfo = {
  name: this.paymentFormGroup.value.name,
  email: this.paymentFormGroup.value.email,
  accountNumber: this.paymentFormGroup.value.accountNumber,
  paymentAmount: payment,
  accountBalance: this.getAccountBalance(payment, balance),
  newAccountBalance: this.getNewBalance(payment, balance),
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want to use external packages, you can listen to formcontrol valueChanges and use currency pipe to modify the value like this

```
constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) { }

ngOnInit() {

const paymentAmountControl = this.paymentFormGroup.get('paymentAmount')

    paymentAmountControl.valueChanges.subscribe((val: string) => {
    val = val.replace(/[a-zA-Z$,]/g, '')

    paymentAmountControl.setValue(this.currencyPipe.transform(val, 'USD', 'symbol', '1.0-0'), { emitEvent: false })
    })
}
```

the regular expression strips alphabets and currency symbols, you will have to modify the regex and the transform argument to support the currency used in your application.

Comment: Thanks... this is somehow eerily taking me back to the early days of .ascx user controls in .Net.
So how/what is "this.control.setValue" referencing the paymentAmount?
And "this.paymentAmount.valueChanges" -- is that syntax to get into the form group?

Comment: sorry, this.control.setValue is the paymentAmountControl, and to get the form control from the form group we need to use the get method, I have updated the answer

Comment: Okay cool, I see that it is modifying the input as it occurs.  The regex is trimming off the decimals, but that doesn't matter.  The key for me was seeing how to get a reference to the control via the formgroup and then subscribing to valueChanges() to modify content.  Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't have a built-in currency formatter. You need to implement custom logic or use some library like [ngx-mask](https://jsdaddy.github.io/ngx-mask-page/main)